isomorphic logging solution with push to server functionality for Next.js app?
I want logging in my Next.js app. Next.js app has code which runs both on server side & client side, so I am looking for a common solution for both sides, so that as a developer I don't have to bother whether a particular piece of code is running on client side or server side. A common solution which works everywhere.
I also want logs which are generated on client side to get pushed to some remote server, so that a developer can monitor app by reading logs on the server while it is live to users.
